# Directory.GetFiles with date in name pattern

Tags: c#, file, filter, directory

I have a issue searching files with Directory class. I have a lot of files with the name similar to this:

**XXX_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS.**

I want to list only the files that have the name with a date in that format and **Directory.GetFiles()** support patterns, but i do not know if there is a pattern that allows me to filter that the name has a date with that format. I thought about using the date of creation or the date of modification, but it is not the same as the one that comes in the name and is the one I need to use.

Does anyone know how to help me? Thanks!

Comment: Is there any reason you can't filter *after* retrieving the filenames?

Comment: Because in the name is the date when that file should be processed ... yes ... I know ... that is very dangerous, but the client wants it that way and does not change his mind: D

Comment: So you can at least filter on the date with a literal string...

Comment: But this requires that i create a literal foreach date, no? i was thinking in each iteration, get the name and try to convert to date. If this works, i can follow the iteration... but i don't know if this is the best way.

Comment: It's still not clear why you need to do this *in the Directory.GetFiles call*. Just fetch all the filenames, and then filter them afterwards.

Answer (score 0):

I suggest *two* steps filtering:

1. Wild cards (raw filtering) `XXX_YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS` where `XXX`, `YYYYMMDD` and `HHMMSS` are some characters
2. Fine filtering (*Linq*) where we ensure `YYYYMMDD_HHMMSS` is a proper date.

Something like this:

```
var files = Directory
 .EnumerateFiles(@"c:\MyFiles", "*_????????_??????.*")    // raw filtering
 .Where(file => {                                         // fine filtering
   string name = Path.GetFileNameWithoutExtension(file);
   // from second last underscope '_' 
   string at = name.Substring(name.LastIndexOf('_', name.LastIndexOf('_') - 1) + 1);

   return DateTime.TryParseExact(                         // is it a proper date?
     at,
     "yyyyMMdd'_'HHmmss",
     CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
     DateTimeStyles.AssumeLocal,
     out var _date); })
 .ToArray();       // Finally, we want an array
```

Answer (score 0):

What about using regex? You could propably use something like this:

```
private static readonly Regex DateFileRegex = new Regex(".*_[0-9]{8}_[\d]{6}.*");

public IEnumerable<string> EnumerateDateFiles(string path)
{
   return Directory.EnumerateFiles(path)
              .Where(x => this.IsValidDateFile(x));
}

private bool IsValidDateFile(string filename)
{
   return DateFileRegex.IsMatch(filename);
}
```

The pattern:

```
 .*_[0-9]{8}_[\d]{6}.*
```

matches

```
 AHJDJKA_20180417_113028sad.jpg
```

for example.

Notice: I couldnt test the code right now. But youll get the idea.

Comment: `Regex` is OK if we can guarantee that pattern is a proper date, if not we are in trouble with *leap years* etc. For instance `ABC_20170229_141516.txt` is not a *valid* file name (`29 Feb 2017`)

Comment: It had not occurred to me to use regex to do this. Thank you!